# how to fix Reverse for 'like_post' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': 5L}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django

I have an error `Reverse for 'like_post' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': 5L}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

I couldn't fix it I tried to change the url.py and even the views.py but the problem persist this is my code :

`views.py`

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect, render_to_response
from django.template import Context
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views.generic import View

from blog.forms import CommentForm, PostForm, SearchForm
from blog.models import Post


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')[0:50]
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'posts': posts})


def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})


def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('blog.views.post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form})


def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/add_post.html', {'form': form})


def search_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        search_text = request.POST['search-form']
    else:
        search_text = ''
    posts = Post.objects.filter(title__contains=search_text)
    return render_to_response('blog/search.html', {'post': posts})


def like_post(request, pk):
    print pk
    if pk:
        post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
        post.likes += 1
        post.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/like/%s' % pk)


def dislike_post(request, pk):
    if pk:
        post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
        post.dislikes += 1
        post.save()
     return HttpResponseRedirect('/like/%s' % pk)
```

and `url.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/comment/$', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
    url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.search_view, name='search'),
    url(r'^like/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.like_post, name='post_like'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/dislike/$', views.dislike_post, name='post_dislike'),
]
```

In the template I use `{% url 'like_post' pk=post.pk %}` but it dosen't work. It seems that urls.py is written incorrectly and I can't find the mistake.

Comment: You are supposed to use 'post_like' (url name) instead of 'like_post' (view name) in a url tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `name` of the url pattern matches the name in the url tag.

In your urls, you are using the name `post_like`.

```
url(r'^like/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.like_post, name='post_like'),
```

Therefore you need to change the url tag to:

```
{% url 'post_like' pk=post.pk %}
```

Alternatively, you could change the name of the url,

```
url(r'^like/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.like_post, name='like_post'),
```

and then the url will work as it is:

```
{% url 'like_post' pk=post.pk %}
```

Personally, I think that changing the url pattern is better. It's less confusing if you use `like_post` for the view name and url name.

Comment: You beat me to it... :D

Comment: Thank you so much I'm feeling so dumb right now for not  fixing that , but honestly I didn't know that the name attribute is so important , after fixing the problem the page works still there is something wrong in my view because the likes dosen't change. thank you !! :)

Comment: Sometimes it takes a second pair of eyes to spot the problem. If the likes count is not working, it might be better to ask a new question.

Comment: totally true , I will post the question later :)